# How to SQL query an Employee table that lists all data on employees whose birthdays fall in October or November?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling to query an Employee table that shows all employee data, but only for those employees whose birthdays fall in October or November (regardless of year).

My table is structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
EMP_NUM integer PRIMARY KEY,
EMP_LNAME varchar2(15),
EMP_FNAME varchar2(12),
EMP_HIREDATE date,
EMP_DOB date
);
```

EMP_DOB is of the format 'MM/DD/YYYY'

I have tried querying into Oracle Live SQL the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE MONTH(EMP_DATE) = '10' OR MONTH(EMP_DATE) = '11'
```

Unfortunately, I get the error message: ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier

**Does anybody know how I could query my Employee table to extract all Employee data on just those employees whose birthdays fall in October or November?**

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html#GUID-36E52BF8-945D-437D-9A3C-6860CABD210E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Month()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) Returns the month for date, in the range 1 to 12 for January to December, or 0 for dates such as '0000-00-00' or '2008-00-00' that have a zero month part.

So, you can use Extract(MONTH FROM dataExpression) to fetch month from date.

your required query is :-

`SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EMP_DOB) IN (10,11);`

Comment: `MONTH()` is not a valid function in Oracle. The documentation you have linked to is for MySQL (and not Oracle).